# Qt: How to detect the right clicked item when using customContextMenuRequested signal

Tags: c++, qt

hello all 
quick question 
im using in Treewidget the customContextMenuRequested signal and using using popup with qmenu 
How can I get the item pointer / object / reference that just bean right clicked before the popup executed
I need to make some validation on the item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That signal contains a `QPoint`, `QWidget::customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint & pos)`, which you can pass to `QTreeWidget::itemAt(const QPoint & p)` which returns a `QTreeWidgetItem`.

Comment: one problem remains when i right click not on tree node i still trigger the customContextMenuRequested SLOT function , how can i check there is its QTreeWidgetItem object?

Comment: The documentation isn't clear on that. I would expect in that case, itemAt() would either return null or the root item.